# Flagging a question that is too broad

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, declined-flags

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18046347/sum-of-1-to-1-000-000-000) question has garnered a lot of attention recently. However, I believe it is too broad and hence should be closed. Indeed, the question *was* successfully closed for this very reason by me and several others, but it was later reopened.

Because I casted a close vote for the initial closing of the question, I cannot revote to close it. So, I flagged it saying "This question is too broad". Sadly, this flag was declined:

[image]

So my question is: was it appropriate of me to flag this question the way I did, given the circumstances? If not, what could/should have been done, if anything?

Additionally, should the linked question actually be considered too broad?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So my question is: was it appropriate of me to flag this question the way I did, given the circumstances? If not, what could/should have been done, if anything?

You already know that, in general, you should not use a moderator flag to close a question. You should just vote to close (or flag as "does not belong here", if you do not have [close vote privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions)).

Unfortunately, you did not convey that knowledge to the moderator who processed your flag. The flag message was insufficiently detailed. It *looked* like you were raising a flag instead of casting a close vote. That's almost guaranteed to be the reason the moderator rejected your flag.

Like you said, you'd already voted to close the question and you can't vote again. There are two schools of thought here on what you should do:

1. The reason you can only vote once (once to close, once to re-open) is because you only get to have one say. If you voted to close, but the question got re-opened, then you simply got overruled/outvoted. That's how the system works, it's entirely by design, and you should just accept that the community does not agree with your opinion and move on to closing other questions.
2. The question really is bad, a bunch of idiots voted to re-open it, and you need a moderator to come in and overrule that decision. If that is truly the case, raising a moderator flag using the "other" reason (as you've done here) is pretty much your only recourse.

   But if you *do* choose to use that strategy, you *must* make sure to explain why you're doing that in the flag reason. Moderators can't read your mind. <sup><sub>[citation-required]</sub></sup>

> Additionally, should the linked question actually be considered too broad?

No. I mean, I don't think so. I think it's a perfectly reasonable question.

It seems to break down like this:

- Here is what I'm trying to do.
- Here is the code I'm trying to use to do it.
- Here is the result I get. It is wrong because…
- However, I am able to obtain the correct result by doing…
- What is wrong with my original code? How can I fix it to get the result I expected?

Isn't that *precisely* what we want a good question to include? Sure, there might be a lot of problems with his/her code, but that doesn't make the question "too broad". That just makes it harder to answer. It is always better to break up problems into multiple, more specific questions, but clearly this person isn't able to debug the problem sufficiently to break it down any more than he did. I don't think it's that big of a deal, the code snippets are short and succinct.

Note that the question has undergone a large number of revisions since it was initially posted. Several of the close voters might have been evaluating an older version of the question. I speak only of the *current* version, which looks fine to me.

Comment: Thank you for the insightful reply; I'm still searching for that required citation. As for the second half of the answer, what about this: "Is it the same problem for other interpreted languages such as Python or Perl?". *Many* of the answers seem to only address that specific question.

Comment: @arshajii Meh, that's just his way of asking "Since it works in Go, does that mean it's a problem with interpreted languages?" It's not really a comparison question, he's just suggesting a theory on why the original PHP code doesn't work. Yes, some of the *answers* are bad. But not the ones near the top. That's not necessarily the fault of the question...

Answer (score 3):

I declined that flag for the simple reason that I disagreed with it. I saw no pressing need to override the community and close that question. It is a specific programming question that is well explained and has received good answers. I personally don't believe such a question should be closed.

Remember that when you flag a question for a moderator to act on, you're asking us to unilaterally close or delete it, with no community consensus. Close vote flags were always the hardest for us to act on, and there's a reason that they now feed into the close vote queue. If five community members vote that something should be closed (or reopened), that shows that there's some kind of agreement that it doesn't fit the scope of the site. We only should need to step in for trolls, spam, and other cases that the community couldn't otherwise handle.

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful.

Comment: That may be why you declined it, but that would make your decline message a false statement, as it implies that the flag is invalid, rather than what it was, a *valid* flag subject to disagreement.

Comment: @ChrisStratton - Not sure why you're arguing about this four years later, but there's nothing false about my statement. It was not a correct use of a custom flag, even if I had agreed that the question was too broad. Custom flags aren't to be used for standard close votes, when there are standard flags / votes for that.

Comment: @BradLarson - no, you are incorrect, because you overlook that the special purpose flagging option is no longer available when a user who *ordinarily* could cast a close vote cannot for the particular question, or already used a special purpose flag on an earlier version.  In that case, a custom flag is the *only* option, and therefore proper if the question that should be closed does need moderator intervention for closureThe only arguable part is if it actually does need to be closed - but in the circumstance, the flag itself is inarguably valid as it is the only way to raise the issue.

Comment: @Chris The only reason you'd be unable to cast a close vote is because you've already cast one before, and in that case, you've already been given the opportunity to voice your concerns. It isn't appropriate to abuse a custom moderator flag so that you have a renewed chance to voice your opinion that the question should be closed. Furthermore, *if* you are going to do this, you need to *explain* that *in detail* in the custom flag message. Otherwise, flags like this are going to get declined every time. Moderators have no way of knowing what goes on in your head.

Comment: You need to re-read the question you are commenting on a mistaken answer to.